# Value of must be an array or a collection (javax.servlet.ServletException)

Tags: java, primefaces

I am getting `javax.faces.FacesException: Value of 'groupList 'must be an array or a collection` error. I've googled for it, but I still don't get an idea as for me it seems I have a collection: it is List, also i see in debugger that it is populated.

form.xhtml:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="groupList" value="">
    <f:selectItems value="#{formBean.groups}"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

formBean.java:

```
...
private List<String> groups;

...
public void initFormBean()
{
    groups = repository.getAllGroups(); // debugger info: groups = (java.util.ArrayList) "size = 138"
}

...
public List<String> getGroups() {
    return groups;
}

public void setGroups(List<String> groups) {
    this.groups = groups;
}
```

Comment: The answer is correct, but please next time post a full stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to bind the value of the checkbox by setting the value-attribute of the p:selectManyCheckbox tag. That way it has somewhere to store which of the possible items have been selected.

See also http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_selectmanycheckbox_tag.htm

Comment: @Andrej don't forget to accept  the answer if this is correct

Comment: Finally it worked with `selectedGroup = null` at bean

Comment: @AQndrej: You modified your question fundamentally after getting an answer and accepted that. That is *not* good, since now the answer does not match the question anymore. And your _'Finally it worked...'_ is a new answer to a new question. I'm going to revert your modifications. And you also do not need to change the title like adding 'UPD'